Compact bilinear form
Let $H, K$ be separable Hilbert spaces and $A: H \times K \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded bilinear form.  We know that by Riesz Theorem, there exists a bounded map $T: H \to K'$ such that $A(u,v) = \langle Tu, v \rangle_{K',K}$ for all $u \in H, v \in K$.
Now assume that $A$ is compact, namely $A(B)$ is precompact for every bounded set in $H \times K$. My question is whether $T$ is also compact?

No, of course not. Check, e.g., the standard scalar product $A(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$ on $H=K=\ell^2$.
